# How to convert from JScript epoch to/from VBScript epoch?

Tags: date, vbscript, epoch, jscript

VBScript represents dates internally as a double, days since "year 0" in the part to the left of the decimal point and the milliseconds since midnight for the current day to the right of the decimal. "Year 0" seems to be 1899 if

```
WScript.Echo Year(CDate(0))
```

can be trusted.

JScript on the other hand starts with a "year 0" of 1970 and represents time as the total milliseconds from then until now.

Can someone point me to code that makes possible conversion of JScript dates to VBScript dates and back again along these lines, of using the underlying Double or Long format of the date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate date using timestamp and convert into double.

```
Function CurrentTZOffset()
    With CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
        CurrentTZOffset = - .RegRead( _ 
        "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\ActiveTimeBias")
    End With
End Function

Dim dblVbEpoch
    dblVbEpoch = CDbl(DateAdd("s", 1336708766790 / 1000, #1970/1/1#))

WScript.Echo "VB Epoch :", dblVbEpoch
WScript.Echo "VB Date (GMT):", CDate(dblVbEpoch)
WScript.Echo "VB Date (LOCAL):", DateAdd("n", CurrentTZOffset(), CDate(dblVbEpoch))
WScript.Echo "JS Epoch From VB Epoch:", DateDiff("s", #1970/1/1#, CDate(dblVbEpoch)) * 1000
```

Comment: There's something amiss with that code. If I set ch to 1336708766790 (11-May-2012 11:59:26.790), and then run that code, it says: 
VB Epoch : 41040.1662731481
VB Date : 11/05/2012 3:59:26 AM
JS Epoch From VB Epoch: 1336708766000

Comment: @boost Actually there's no. It is based on GMT as it should be. JS shows local dates depends on operating system, locale, or browser. e.g. `new Date(1336708766790)` will returns `11-May-2012 06:59:26.790` for me beacuse of time zone. If you want localizing the date, you need to get current timezone offset. I updated answer regarding this.

Comment: js returns milliseconds, so parseInt((new Date).getTime()  / 1000) = proper_epoch.

Comment: @ekerner It's correct but was not the case here. This was all about VBScript, which handles dates with a diferent epoch. BTW **epoch is not epoch in any language**. An epoch date is a reference time point and it depends on platform. `00:00:00 UTC, January 1, 1970` is Unix Time Stamp's epoch. You can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) other epoch dates existing.

Comment: Wow. I concede. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Epoch is epoch in any language, number of seconds past since 00:00:00 UTC, January 1, 1970.

```
 'Get current epoch with vbScript ...
  dim epoch
  epoch = dateDiff("s", "01/01/1970 00:00:00", now())
  wScript.echo "epoch now = " & epoch
```

> epoch now = 1346891880

```
 'And convert it back (probably the one you need) ...
  dim datetime
  datetime = dateAdd("s", epoch, "01/01/1970 00:00:00")
  wScript.echo "datetime from epoch " & epoch & " = " & datetime
```

> datetime from epoch 1346891880 = 6/09/2012 12:38:00 AM

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in converting between VBScript dates and JScript dates, that functionality is built into JScript, via the [`Date` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd9w2te4%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) and the [`getVarDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d4x3w61%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method.

A small example:

```
<job id="test">
    <script language="JScript" id="jsLibrary">
        function JSExample() {
            var jsDate = new Date(2014, 4, 12);
            VBPrintJSDate(jsDate);
        }

        function JSPrintVBDate(vbDate) {
            var jsDate = new Date(vbDate);
            WScript.Echo(jsDate.toUTCString());
        }
    </script>
    <script language="VBScript" id="vbLibrary">
        Option Explicit

        Sub VBExample
            Dim vbDate
            vbDate = DateSerial(2000, 11, 30)
            JSPrintVBDate(vbDate)
        End Sub

        Sub VBPrintJSDate(jsDate)
            Dim vbDate
            vbDate = jsDate.getVarDate()
            WScript.Echo FormatDateTime(vbDate)
        End Sub
    </script>
    <script language="VBScript" id="main">
        Option Explicit

        VBExample
        JSExample
    </script>
</job>
```